# Multi-Tenant Azure AD Auth in Azure AD B2C with Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use Azure AD Auth in Azure AD B2C using the /common Azure AD enpoint. According to [How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values), there needs to be a mechanism to either:

1. Allow multiple issuers, or
2. Specify a list of issuers b2c can validate against.

I do not see any possible setting in the custom policies XML that would allow this. I was able to get Azure AD auth created successfully in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file, just not multi-tenant now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to support multi-tenant Azure AD, you'll need to configure your ClaimsProvider in the custom policy with different  values.

Use the values below, making sure you replace with client_id and IdTokenAudience.

```xml
<Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
<Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
<Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize</Item>
<Item Key="client_id">df5b2515-a8d2-4d91-ab4f-eac6e1e416c2</Item>
<Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
<Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
<Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
<Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
<Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
<Item Key="IdTokenAudience">df5b2515-a8d2-4d91-ab4f-eac6e1e416c2</Item>
```

CAUTION: This functionality isn't officially even in preview yet, so use with caution. Keep monitoring the [official "Sign in by using Azure AD accounts" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) to see when this is fully documented and supported.

## EDIT:

**This functionality is now in preview**, see the official documentation for this: [Allow users to sign in to a multi-tenant Azure AD identity provider using custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom)