# Multi-tenant Azure AD in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was following the answer here: [Multi-Tenant Azure AD Auth in Azure AD B2C with Custom Policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526054/multi-tenant-azure-ad-auth-in-azure-ad-b2c-with-custom-policies)

And the walkthrough here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/0129fc013ae5e66a3ee0046a5d0db2e8120d8f8e/Walkthroughs/IdP-AzureAD.md

But I wasn't able to login, the error message is something along the line:

```
AADB2C: An exception has occured. Correlation ID: <GUID>. Timestamp: <Time>
```

Furthermore, when viewing the walkthrough in latest master, the whole page has been removed and now only contains the link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom, which does not show how to configure ClaimsProvider for multi-tenant Azure AD IDP.

The error message was not super helpful, and I'm getting lost.

My technical profile is as follow:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>AzureAD</Domain>
    <DisplayName>Login using Azure AD</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AzureADProfile">
            <DisplayName>Azure AD</DisplayName>
            <Description>Login with your Azure AD account</Description>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
            <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
                <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
                <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
                <Item Key="client_id">MyAzureADB2CAppId</Item>
                <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">MyAzureADB2CAppId</Item>
                <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
                <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
                <Item Key="BearerTokenTransmissionMethod">AuthorizationHeader</Item>
                <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
                <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
                <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_B2CSecret"/>
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="azureADAuthentication" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="AzureAD" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

**EDIT:** After introducing User Journey Recorder as per spottedhahn's suggestion, I've managed to get the real error:

```
The response received from the ClaimsProvider using TechnicalProfile 
"<My_Azure_AD_Common_Profile>" in policy "<My_RP_Policy>" of tenant 
"<My_B2C_Tenant>" did not contain an "id_token".
```

The question is: **Is linking multi-tenant Azure AD to Azure AD B2C still supported, and how can I configure to make that work?**

Comment: Using the [user journey recorder](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%205.md#using-the-user-journey-recorderplayer) might provide more details than "an exception has occurred"

Comment: @spottedmahn I tried setting up using b2crecorder.azurewebsites.net but no log appears on trace_102.html

Comment: Perhaps another thread would be better to troubleshoot.  I’ve used in the past so I know it works.  I’ve messed up the viewing url in the past.

Comment: I managed to get the log from my own web-app, the error is `The response received from the ClaimsProvider using TechnicalProfile "<My_Azure_AD_Common_Profile>" in policy "<My_RP_Policy>" of tenant "<My_B2C_Tenant>" did not contain an "id_token".`. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Have reviewed this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

Comment: Yea I did. The guide there is about setting up for single-tenant Azure AD, and I was able to do so. But there's no mention of multi-tenant (using common endpoint), which is what I'm trying to achieve now.

Comment: Can you please post your Azure AD technical profile here?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett just did, please have a look.

Comment: Hi @HarryNinh Did you create the app registration for the Azure AD B2C tenant in the Azure AD tenant using [the Application Registration portal](https://identity.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett No, I created it through "Azure AD B2C" blade in the portal. When I tried to register app in identity.microsoft.com, it redirected me to apps.dev.microsoft.com, which listed app in my corporate tenant (e.g. contoso.com), but my B2C tenant is different (e.g. fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com). Should I go on with using an app on my contoso.com? Shouldn't it be in a more 'common' place?

Comment: To federate from Azure AD B2C to Azure AD, you must register your web app through the Azure AD B2C portal with your Azure AD B2C tenant and then register your Azure AD B2C tenant through the Application Registration portal with your Azure AD tenant.

Comment: I have Azure AD B2C Web App, do you have any document on registering that app with Azure AD tenant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When federating Azure AD B2C with Azure AD's common endpoint, you can integrate with either:

- The v1.0 endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`
- The v2.0 endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

**v1.0 endpoint**

To integrate Azure AD B2C with the v1.0 endpoint, you must register Azure AD B2C through [the Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) with your Azure AD tenant:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. In the top bar, select your Azure AD directory.
3. In the left bar, select **All services** and find "App registrations".
4. Select **New application registration**.
5. In **Name**, enter an application name, such as "Azure AD B2C".
6. In **Application type**, select **Web app / API**.
7. In **Sign-on URL**, enter `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant>/oauth2/authresp`, where you replace `<tenant>` with the name of your Azure AD B2C tenant (such as "contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com").
8. Select **Create**.
9. Copy **Application ID** for later.
10. Select **Settings** and then select **Keys**.
11. In the **Passwords** section, enter a password description, select a password duration, select **Save**, and then copy the password value for later.

You must then create a policy key (e.g. "AzureADClientSecret") through the Azure AD B2C portal with the application secret from step 11.

You must then update the Azure AD technical profile with the following settings:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureADAccountProfile">
  <DisplayName>Log in with your work account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
  <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id"><!-- Enter the application ID from step 9 --></Item>
    <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience"><!-- Enter the application ID from step 9 --></Item>
    <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
    <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AzureADClientSecret"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="enterpriseAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="tid" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**v2.0 endpoint**

To integrate Azure AD B2C with the v2.0 endpoint, you must register Azure AD B2C through [the Application Registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) with your Azure AD tenant:

1. Sign in to the Application Registration portal.
2. Select **Add an app**.
3. In **Application Name**, enter an application name, such as "Azure AD B2C", and then select **Create**.
4. Copy **Application Id** for later.
5. In the **Application Secrets** section, select **Generate new password** and then copy the password value for later.
6. In the **Platforms** section, select **Add Platform**, select **Web**, and then enter a **Redirect URL** as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenant>/oauth2/authresp`, where you replace `<tenant>` with the name of your Azure AD B2C tenant (such as "contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com").
7. In the bottom bar, select **Save**.

You must then create a policy key (e.g. "AzureADClientSecret") through the Azure AD B2C portal with the application secret from step 5.

You must then update the Azure AD technical profile with the following settings:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureADAccountProfile">
  <DisplayName>Log in with your work account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
  <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
    <Item Key="client_id"><!-- Enter the application ID from step 4 --></Item>
    <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience"><!-- Enter the application ID from step 4 --></Item>
    <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
    <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
    <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AzureADClientSecret"/>
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="enterpriseAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="tid" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I've done that v2.0 walkthrough in the past, but with a small but important mistake: I created the app under "Azure AD only applications", whereas I should have done under "Converged applications". Redid it again today and it works! So if you could edit your answer and put that details in for others, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @ChrisPadgett, the Azure Portal now has a new "Application Registrations (Preview)" section on the AD blade. (Deep link: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredAppsPreview). 

Question: Do we still need to register the app over on the App Registration Portal or can we do this on this "preview" blade? I don't see apps registered on one show up on the other one, though the on-screen guidance seem to indicate that the Azure Portal preview blade UI is the "recommended" way now.

Comment: Hi @SujaySarma. Yes, you can use the App Registrations (Preview) blade in the Azure portal, to register Azure AD B2C with Azure AD. When I have a few minutes, I'll add to the above answer. Thank you!