# Can Azure AD (work) accounts be used with Azure B2C? Is that a bad idea?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I need to support work accounts (or school accounts) with AzureAD B2C.

I already have an existing base of Facebook clients and Google. However, when I configure the Microsoft endpoint, I only get the liveID option.

Is there a way to use a custom B2C signup policy to use AAD? What other solutions exist?

Comment: Somehow this very broad question received 5 upvotes and this question ended up as [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49133390/timeline). This simply needs to be closed.

Comment: With respect to @K.Dᴀᴠɪs and the other closers, I don't understand why this is too broad. Azure AD B2C "flavor" doesn't have a clear-cut way to authenticate AzureAD/Office365 accounts.  This question attempts to connect the Identity Providers in a consistent and logical way. Furthermore there is an answer that bridges the authentication silos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to enable sign-in for users from **a specific Azure AD**. 
You can refer to [**this guide**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) to achieve that.

However, I also want to make clear that these AAD accounts is not be authenticated for Office 365. When you use Azure AD accounts to sign-in AAD B2C applications, Azure AD is just as a identity provider in Azure AD B2C like others, such as  Microsoft Account and Google+.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if it is only possible to use a single tenant there or is it possible to allow any tenant to sign in by using custom policies?

Comment: Hi @juunas. Custom policies can support both the single- and multiple-tenant scenarios. See [Multi-tenant Azure AD in Azure AD B2C
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897555/multi-tenant-azure-ad-in-azure-ad-b2c/49019341) for how to federate Azure AD B2C with Azure AD's common endpoint for multiple tenants.

Comment: Is any token returned that allows for graph access using a different library? (e.g. B2C Facebook auth allowing FB access, B2C AAD auth allowing graph access?)

Comment: @TLDR Did you ever work out if this is possible? Trying to work out how to approach a similar problem and require using AAD to sign in but need access to the graph.

Comment: I've tried the AZ AD single-tenant, and read about the AZ AD multi-tenant approaches but both approaches seem to be creating an extra button for each AD login instance. Is it possible to have a single "Log in with Work Account" button and internally handle the redirect to the right AD?