# AADB2C99002 error. B2C Sign In policy without Sign Up policy?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to implement authentication via Azure AD B2C by only configuring a **SignIn** Policy, without any SignUp or SignUpSignIn policies?

The idea is to add users from the Azure B2C portal instead of allowing users to register themselves via any kind of sign-up form.

When trying to do this I keep getting the following error:

```
AADB2C99002: User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.
```

Please help.

It's been already asked here, with no answer: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20440876-aadb2c99002-user-does-not-exist-please-sign-up-b

Comment: are you using userflows or custom policies. Both modes support a sign in only user flow.

Comment: I am using user flows. I want the users to use their already-existing Microsoft or AAD account. Maybe sign in only is possible as you say, but only by creating B2C users (but I want to reuse the already-existing Microsoft account, not to create a new one with a different password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sign in with only B2C user. Navigate to *Azure AD B2C -> Users* in the portal, and there are the users who can sign in.

**Add users or invite external user in the portal.**

1. Create a B2C user:
   [image]

[image]

2. Sign in with the user in a "Sign in" user flow:

[image]

3. Return the id token successfully:

[image]

---

**Add users or invite external user using Microsoft Graph API.**

[Create user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Adele Vance",
  "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
  "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
  }
}
```

[Invite user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 551

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.contoso.com"
}
```

You could test them in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I assume it's not possible to implement sign in only by using users' already-existing Microsoft/AAD accounts. I necessarily need to create B2C users (and therefore, the password the users use may be different from the password used by their Microsoft/AAD accounts).

Comment: The accounts that I mentioned are Guest accounts or Consumer accounts, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview). If you want to sign Azure AD(Work) account in, try to use Custom Policies to enable sign-in for users from a specific Azure AD, and refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49134987/13308381.

Comment: @PamelaPeng Do you happen to know if Microsoft Graph (via Invitations) can be used to invite Consumer (specifically just Consumer) B2C users to a B2C tenant? I can create such accounts but have not been successful inviting them using Microsoft Graph, either v1 or Beta. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @IdusOrtus. Invitations API is used to invite external users to your tenant as a guest user. But in your side, you have created a [consumer user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview). If you invite it again, it will return "User name already exists in this directory".

Comment: @PamelaPeng-MSFT I have a similar [AADB2C99002 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71932856/5063031). Seems using `B2C tenant` won't need sign-up first, and `AZ AD B2C` does. But choosing a `B2C tenant` does not have App Registration. Under Overview there is `Azure AD B2C Settings Open B2C Tenant` link, click on it opens up the corresponding Azure AD B2C directory created when this B2C tenant was created. This is where my app is registered, `Identity providers` are set up, `User flows` gave me the error.