# Azure AD B2C and MS Teams app (bot + tab) auth

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-teams, aad-b2c

We are working on integrating our app with MS Teams using a Teams app with a bot and a tab and we are struggling with the authentication.

Our scenario is:

- We use Azure AD B2C for authentication to our app (using predefined user flows).
- We have different customers that use Azure AD (each one with its own Azure AD tenant). We created a [custom identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow) that enables sign-in/sign up users to our app using their own Azure AD credentials.
- We created a bot channel registration using a "Generic Oauth 2" service provider to connect to our bot with Azure AD B2C.

Our challenges are:

- Ideally, we want to implement SSO for our bot in Teams to allow our customers to be able to sign in to our app using their MS Teams credentials. We managed to authenticate using `OAuthPrompt` for Teams following this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth) but the challenge we've seen is that the user needs to sign in every time that opens the bot (i.e. there refresh token is not working) and also we are not able to send a "domain_hint" query string to differentiate our customers.
- Ideally, we want the authentication to be handled using only one bot channel registration
  Probably it could be achieved by creating one channel registration for each customer but in the long-term, we'd need to create one bot for each customer and that could be difficult to maintain/avoiding our customers installing an App Registration on their Azure AD.

Anyone had similar experiences dealing with MS Teams apps for multiple Azure AD tenants using Azure AD B2C? How's the best way you recommend to handle this scenario?

Your help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps to someone, after some research, we are doing the following for our scenario:

- For the SSO in the tabs, given the limitation of `OAuthPrompt` to don't refresh tokens (we don't want users to sign in every time the token expires) we are following this solution posted months ago https://github.com/igrep/example-teams-bot-with-ms-account-refresh-token.
- For handling multiple Azure AD tenants within B2C, given that we are using predefined user flows and we need to build a custom sign-in for our scenario, we are going to pass the get and pass the `domain_hint` from MS Teams to Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

- To implement SSO, please go through [Add single sign on to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml) and also you can refer the code base in [Expert Finder](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-expertfinder/blob/master/Source/ExpertFinder/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs) app template and it has implemented the same bot sign-in functionality and it is working fine.
- Could you please take a look at multiple [Azure AD tenants using Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897555/multi-tenant-azure-ad-in-azure-ad-b2c) for configuring multi tenant AD B2C.

Comment: Many thanks for your response @Meghana-MSFT,  I've taken a look at the links you sent, The SSO it's only available for Azure AD but unfortunately not for Azure AD B2C.

After some research prob I found the solution, will post it as an answer below.

Thanks again!