# Azure ad b2c multi tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Just wondering whether you can help with my question below? O

Does Microsoft Azure AD B2C support multi tenant application? For example,

I created an Azure B2C service call Tenant A, link the service to my subscription account. Then I create the user TenantAAdmin as an admin (global administrator) for this tenant. This admin user be able to assign or create other user in the Azure AD B2C.

I created another Azure B2C service call Tenant B, link the service to my subscription account. Then I create the user TenantBAdmin as an admin (global administrator) for this tenant. This admin user be able to assign or create other user in the Azure AD B2C.

I had an service API e.g. monitor patient health services , this service API will be used for all tenants. How can I register this web API so that users in Tenant A and users in Tenant B are able to access and use the service?

Regards

Tom

Answer (score 3):

You can use Custom policy implementation in Azure AD B2C to achieve multi tenant system for authentication.

Here is a very nice article covering all the scenario for configuring multi tenant system:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2017/07/27/developing-an-azure-ad-b2c-multi-tenant-application/

Also you can check our below QnA for reference

[Multi-tenant Azure AD in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897555/multi-tenant-azure-ad-in-azure-ad-b2c)

and

[Multi-Tenant Azure AD Auth in Azure AD B2C with Custom Policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526054/multi-tenant-azure-ad-auth-in-azure-ad-b2c-with-custom-policies)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to enable sign-in for users using the multi-tenant endpoint for Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) in Azure AD B2C. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom.