# Azure B2C Guest (External Azure Active Directory) X Member (Federated Azure Active Directory)

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-ad-b2c, federated-identity

I implemented what's described in this doc:

[Set up sign-in for multi-tenant Azure Active Directory using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom)

It's related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44532670/114029) on SO.

Can we get a **Guest (External Azure Active Directory)** instead of a **Member (Federated Azure Active Directory)** added to the B2C Users list when logging in from a different tenant?

Is it always going to be a Member (Federated Azure Active Directory) when logging in from a different tenant?

I couldn't find any other information on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An external account user, i.e. those who log in and register through a built-in or custom flow, must be created as a "Member"-type user in Azure AD B2C where their external identity is added to the **userIdentities** property of the **user** object.

Otherwise, you can use the guest functionality to add external users from other tenants, to co-manage your Azure AD B2C tenant.